# Any way to know what files were in a broken ZFS pool?

Tags: solaris, zfs, solaris-10

I have a large ZFS pool of 4 combined drives. Now, the filesystem can not be mounted:

```
  pool: tank
 state: UNAVAIL
status: One or more devices could not be opened.  There are insufficient
        replicas for the pool to continue functioning.
action: Attach the missing device and online it using 'zpool online'.
   see: http://www.sun.com/msg/ZFS-8000-3C
  scan: none requested
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        tank        UNAVAIL      0     0     0  insufficient replicas
          c10t0d0   ONLINE       0     0     0
          c8t0d0    UNAVAIL      0     0     0  cannot open
          c8t1d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
          c10t1d0   ONLINE       0     0     0
```

Probably a broken drive (`c8t0d0`).

I'm not overly concerned by the loss of the data, but I'd love to know exactly which files were in that pool. Is there any way to get a listing of what files were there?

Comment: Why does it matter? You've lost some of the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks as though your pool, `tank`, is comprised of four disks in a striped configuration; e.g. RAID-0 with no redundancy.

Try bringing the disk back online (reseat it, if it's hot-pluggable), check its connections. Run the `zpool online` command, as given in the error message. See what happens. Short of that, I don't believe there's a way to get a listing of the files.

Comment: The freezer method may work if the drive is just barely failing. =]

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried this myself but you could try the ZFS debugger **zdb** to get that information. Here's more about it: http://www.cuddletech.com/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=980.

Comment: That link no longer works :(. This is probably a similar link: https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/man/8/zdb.8.html.